# How to use Storage for darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart in both way?

Tags: laravel, authentication, shopping-cart

I'm using [darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart](https://github.com/darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart) for my Laravel Project.
For saving storage & cart items in this package there is two way [[documents]](https://github.com/darryldecode/laravelshoppingcart#storage)(`'storage' => null` for saving the cart in cache & cookies and `'storage' => App\DBStorage::class` for saving the cart in database)

I want to know how to use both methods for saving the cart items at the same time for Auth users & unregistered users

1. 'storage' => null for unregistered user
2. 'storage' => App\DBStorage::class for the login users

Comment: You can check out my answer on [Store cart data in laravel using Darryldecode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61309436/how-can-i-store-my-cart-data-to-database-in-laravel-using-darryldecode-cart-func/62214982#62214982) Hope it helps.